# TextBox привязанный к Double. Как выводить пустое значение?

Tags: wpf, binding

Здравствуйте.
При привязке TextBox к полю Double **значением по умолчанию** (пока ничего не записали в Val) в TextBox **появляется 0**

Есть ли какие то способы До момента пока пользователь отредактирует поле(!) не показывать 0. (при том что значение 0, вписанное пользователем - допустимо)

Класс:

```
public class TreeDoubleElem
{
   public double Val { get; set; } //значение параметра
}
```

XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Val}" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

Comment: Обновил ответ, смотрите.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проще всего так:

```
public class TreeDoubleElem
{
    public double? Val { get; set; }
}
```

Значение `null` отображается как пустая строка. (Но не забудьте ещё реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged`!)

---

*Старый ответ:*

Например, так:

```
public class TreeDoubleElem
{
    double? val = null;
    string valStr = "";
    public string Val
    {
        get { return valStr; }
        set
        {
            if (valStr == value) return;
            double result;
            if (!double.TryParse(value, out result))
                throw new ArgumentException();
            val = result;
            valStr = value;
            // а здесь неплохо бы вызвать NotifyPropertyChanged ещё
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
А возможно ли Val после того как в нем что то будет записано сбросить до null?

Comment: @trancer1019: `Val = null` не подходит?

Answer (score 2):

Можно изменить значение по умолчанию:

```
private double _value = Double.NaN;
public double Value
{
    get { return _value; }
    set { _value = value; }
}
```

Comment: Красиво! А `double.NaN` будет отображаться как пустая строка?

Comment: @VladD, нет) но я как понял автору нужно главное не отображать 0 пока значение не введено

Comment: О, я нашёл выход: заменить `double` на `double?`.

Comment: @VladD, теперь вообще красиво)